# MVC SelectList postback property not bound

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a select list that is created in my controller as follows:

```
ViewBag.AreaId = new SelectList(
    db.Areas.Where(a => a.ProjectId == vm.Project.ProjectId), 
    "AreaId", 
    "", 
    analyserHouse.AreaId);
```

where `vm` is my own viewmodel that has `AreaId` as property of one of the objects in the viewmodel.

In my create.cshtml im inserting the selectlist as per MVC default:

```
@Html.DropDownList(
    "AreaId", 
    null, 
    htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Controller method:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Create(
    string reference, 
    [Bind(Include = "AreaId,
                     Name,
                     AnalyserHouseType,
                     Length,
                     Width,
                     Height,
                     WallThickness,
                     RoofThickness,
                     FloorThickness,
                     AreaClassificationInside,
                     AreaClassificationOutside,
                     FireRating,
                     FireRatingDoors")] AnalyserHouse analyserHouse)
```

`AnalyserHouse` is an entity of which all properties are correctly bound, except `AreaId`. I tried changing the name to match the viewmodel properties but what I try I cant get `AreaId` to show any value other than 0.

My viewmodel consists of:

```
public class AnalyserHousesDetailViewModel : SidcBaseViewModel
{
    public AnalyserHouse AnalyserHouse { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Is it displaying options in the DropDown?

Comment: Yes. Only that the value is not transferred on postback.

Comment: In your @Html.DropDownList where are you associating the ViewBag.AreaId Select List?

Comment: Is this fiddle anywhere close to your scenario? https://dotnetfiddle.net/fjE3dW

Comment: Is it possible to post your entire view?

Comment: You need to show more of you view. Your model is `AnalyserHousesDetailViewModel` but you method accepts parameter `AnalyserHouse`. Why are you not using strongly type helpers to bind to your properties? Why do you have that awful `[Bind]` include attribute and use a `ViewBag` property if you have a view model? If you have a property named `AreaId` then you need a different name for the select list and use `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.AnalyserHouse.AreaId, (SelectList)ViewBag.AreaList, new { @class = "form-control" })`

Comment: Because the initial viewmodel that I us to create the page has many more properties that are used in the layout of the page, and it contains essentially only the analyserhouse entity that I use in the form to edit. That is why i was using that in the postback. I'm using [bind] because I'm following the ASP.NET MVC tutorials, this also explains the selectlist as this all came from the scaffolds :-) Then after the scaffold I started using the viewmodels... Im learning.

Answer (score 0):

Stephen's suggestion fixed the problem:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.AnalyserHouse.AreaId, (SelectList)ViewBag.AreaList, new { @class = "form-control" })
```